# What is the best strategy to display pdf with php without pdf supporting browser?

Tags: php, pdf

I want to serve pdf files in my raspberry pi web-server so I can read them in devices not supporting native pdf.

As example, I would like to see some pdf's in my samsung smart TV.

What would be the best strategy for it? I'm learning php, so it would be the preferred language.

Thanks,
Jorge

Comment: None. php is a server side language, it does not offer such means apart from some theoretical approach. Take a look at javascript instead, there are some solutions. For example I know that the owncloud.org project offers something like that.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a [PDF](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php) reader available as a module. It won't be able to read all PDF files though.